# Terminating Cat5 for Voice

Tags: cabling

Is there a reason to punch down all four pairs of a cable on a 66 or 110 block if I'm only going to have one twisted pair connected on the other side?

(I hope this is the right site for this).

Comment: Punch them all as others have said.  http://www.vdvworks.com/UncleTed/term.html.  You need to decide on 568A vs 568B.  568B is more common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's infrastructure wiring, then punch all of them.  You never know what might be need in the future.  If it's just a loose cable, then it doesn't much matter as the other pairs can be terminated whenever needed.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a Cat5 cable, but you didn't specify what jack is on "the other side".  Punch down all of the pairs that are physically connected on the other end.  (If you're just running 4 wires to a POTS jack, there's no need to punch down the spare pairs.)